# Monitor and MacBook Pro not on speaking terms anymore

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hdmi, dvi

This one puzzles me.  I have this setup

[MBP]<----[HDMI]----[HDMI-DVI Adapter]---->[BenQ FP222W]

When I plug in the monitor, the MBP detects it and the screen flashes like normal.  Likewise the monitor detects "Input: DVI" and the backlight comes on. Then nothing.
I can move windows to and from the blank screen (they don't display, but they do move there), and as far as my computer seems to know, it's connected.

But here's the weird part, I've tested every component and everything works:

- Monitor with new laptop and same cable -- WORKS
- Monitor with my laptop and DVI cable (DVI to displayport) -- WORKS
- Different monitor with original cable -- WORKS
- Different monitor with just HDMI cable -- WORKS
- Monitor with VGA cable (VGA to displayport) from different computer -- WORKS
- Monitor with DVI cable to different laptop -- WORKS

What am I missing?  I've verified that all the outputs on my laptop work, all the inputs on the monitor work, and all the cables work.  I'm out of ideas (and also curious to see what other people think).

Just to cover a few bases, I tried holding the cable at different angles, I tried leaving the monitor off (in case the gremlins inside can be killed with a lack of electricity), and the monitor was working on Friday Jan 2 (then I was gone all week last week, and it started being picky yesterday morning).

Comment: You did good so far...what os x? what does it show in about this mac monitor type/connection... any console info for the WindowServer? what resolution setting?

Comment: Yosemite 10.10.1 (14B25), MacBook Pro (Retina, Mid 2012) (A1398)

Comment: Have you tried rebooting the mac with the monitor cable connected? Sometimes that fixes it.

Comment: @jsd That sounds just hacky enough to try.  I'll do that when I can stop what I'm doing now (so soon) and let you know.

Comment: Alright, so that fixed it.  Weird.  @jsd, answer with that comment and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reboot the Mac with the monitor cable connected. That sometimes fixes it.